# Double BSODs in a week (new pc)

Tags: bsod, computer-building

PC Specs:

- GPU: Gigabyte 2060 6GB
- CPU: Ryzen 3600x
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 8 GB x2
- MB: Gigabyte B450M S2H
- Adata 240 GB SSD
- Seagate 1 TB HDD

So, I have just built this PC a week ago and it's pretty good. But I have already got two BSODs; first one being `win32kfull.sys` while playing TF2 (game froze with looping sound then immediately gave blue screen), and the other one being `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` while playing Minecraft (Hypixel pit where tons of people are around).

My games also freeze for a millisecond randomly (in bdo mmorpg and such) and I get low fps in Hypixel lobbies when its showing high for me (I mean stutters)
I tried memtest which the hammer test took long but it gave no errors.

I'm worried if its related to my hardware or my drivers.
What should I do now? Should I change them?

_

```
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\012220-10187-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: hal.dll (hal+0x47FE8) 
Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x4, 0xFFFFDD0FC7640038, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
file path: C:\Windows\system32\hal.dll
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred. This bug check uses the error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA). 
This is likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

On Wed 1/22/2020 1:18:04 PM your computer crashed or a problem was reported

```
crash dump file: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP
This was probably caused by the following module: pshed.dll (PSHED!PshedBugCheckSystem+0x10) 
Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x4, 0xFFFFDD0FC7640038, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
file path: C:\Windows\system32\pshed.dll
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Platform Specific Hardware Error Driver
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred. This bug check uses the error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA). 
This is likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.
```

On Fri 1/17/2020 5:06:31 PM your computer crashed or a problem was reported

```
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\011720-9359-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: win32kfull.sys (0xFFFF9E19ECA34A80) 
Bugcheck code: 0x109 (0xA39FCCDA9708BB02, 0xB3B6D960E98B8493, 0xFFFF9E19ECA34A80, 0xC)
Error: CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION
file path: C:\Windows\system32\win32kfull.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Full/Desktop Win32k Kernel Driver
Bug check description: This indicates that the kernel has detected critical kernel code or data corruption. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. This might be a case of memory corruption. This may be because of a hardware issue such as faulty RAM, overheating (thermal issue) or because of a buggy driver. This problem might also be caused because of overheating (thermal issue). 
The crash took place in a Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.
```

Comment: Have you got up-to-date graphics drivers?

Comment: When commercial computers do this without apparent cause, I usually update BIOS, Chipset (if there is one), Video driver, power driver, NIC drivers and RST driver (rapid storage). Try this.

Comment: im worried if its hardware related, how can i check that since one was uncorrectable whea?

Comment: Could you post your `.dmp` files?

Comment: I can do that tomorrow unfortunately

Comment: I would make sure I were not overclocking _anything_. Overclocking can cause this.

Comment: With it being a new PC, if it's a hardware issue, it can be tough to determine which piece of hardware it is. I would update all drivers first, and see what that does. If you have the same issues, I would then move your GPU to a different PCIe slot if you have one available.

Comment: Open your minidump with WhoCrashed, it should suggest a resolution.

Comment: here are the result from WhoCrashed

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same error, also on a Ryzen CPU desktop. After trying a lot of things with updates, drivers, bios versions, and DRAM voltages -- none of which yielding any improvement -- I finally discovered that it was a heat issue. I'm not overclocking my machine in any way, but once I opened the case and let it run like that, the `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` stopped occurring.

Not sure why Windows is so fragile. Under Linux everything was stable even when hogging the CPU for several minutes using `stress --cpu 12`. Also the CPU should have throttled to keep temperature under control, like my previous Intel did. But so be it. At least I found the cause in my case -- literally ;-)